# send data to a web page

Tags: iphone, web-services, nsurlconnection, nsurl

I have a web page(the technology use it on is html and aspx) that let the user to send free SMS... i want to send the userName, password, text message, receiver number and the date from my iphone app...
 How can i do that ?

Comment: the asp.net tag is irrelevant in this case, as you would need to use standard http-technologies as GET or POST.

Comment: sorry i use apsx not asp.net i will change the tag

Answer (score 0):

You need some kind of **WebService** to do these operations.